# Data Filter - some fields greyed out

Tags: marketing-cloud

Has anyone had issues where some of the fields in a data filter cannot be selected?

I've created a **data relationship** between two data extension.  The first DE contains just a few field and has `EmailAddress` as the primary key.  This DE is related to a second table and is joined on the `EmailAddress` field.  The second table has a primary key that uses multiple fields, but `EmailAddress` is not one of these fields.  (the second table is part of an existing process and I cannot change it's structure)

[image: Data Relationship Screenshot]

When I attempt to create a **data filter** on the first table, the primary key fields in the second table are not selectable.  Below are screenshot of both the data relationship config and filter.

[image: Filter Screenshot]